# Is it legal if I ram a drone into another drone?

Tags: india, drones

1. I am aware that I'm not allowed to shoot at someone's drone. However, what happens if my drone crashes into another drone? Is it treated like a car crash?
2. What is the fastest and most efficient way to get rid of a drone?

This question is partly inspired by Randall Munroe's new book. I have no idea about law.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to "shoot down" a drone on your property in the US?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19526/is-it-legal-to-shoot-down-a-drone-on-your-property-in-the-us)

Comment: Clarify what you actually want to know about. Is it the legality of interfering with drones, or the use of drones affecting privacy? This is both too broad and unclear, and also potentially a duplicate of existing questions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the OP is not asking if its possible - they are asking if its legal.

Comment: By definition, a question about Indian law is not a duplicate of a question about US law.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo but this is Law SE - Physics SE or Electrical Engineering SE are available if that's what you want to know.

Comment: @Nij no it isnt. shooting != ramming into

Comment: Physically interfering with a drone is the same thing regardless of how you do it.

Comment: @Nij possibly not, at least inasmuch as (1) certain methods of interference, such as shooting, may be illegal of themselves, and (2) the consequences of the interference may give rise to different degrees of liability, for example if different methods result in different degrees or kinds of damage to the drone.

Answer (score 1):

### What right to privacy?

To the extent that you have a right to privacy, you have to be in a private space and that right extends only to the extent that you are not observable from a public space. For example, you have a right to privacy in your bedroom *if* you close the curtains.

Any such space is almost certainly indoors where drones are unlikely to be an issue.

### You can’t break other people’s stuff

You just can’t. If you do it negligently, you have to pay for it. If you do it deliberately, you have to pay for it *and* you’re committing a crime.

### What you can do

Drone use is increasingly regulated. If they are breaching the regulations, report it to the regulator.

It’s possible that you could succeed in a [nuisance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance) suit if you can identify the operator.

Comment: @user8412585 As the answer suggests, a lawsuit for damages or seeking a court order prohibiting the drone from being used may be possible if you can find out who owns it. But, it is entirely possible that the drone is being used lawfully and that there is no legal remedy, or that it is not possible as a practical matter to identify the owner.

Comment: I rather suspect that some courts in the world have found or will find that a private yard, screened from the public way by a fence or other obstacle, is a private space.

Answer (score -1):

Drones have no rights. Owners of drones may have the right that nobody destroys their property without a very good reason.